# Problem using dist2isobath function (marmap package) with projected coordinate system

Tags: r, utm

I have a grid with created in an projected coordinate system (WGS84 zone 30N) and I am trying to extract the smallest distance from all of the cells of the grid to the coast and to other isobaths using the funcion "dist2isobath" from the package marmap.

To do this I reprojected the ETOPO1 data (ocean bathymetry) to the same projection as the data of my grid, then used the "dist2isobath" function but it gives me an error. Aparently it only works with geographic (see the error below). Do you know how can I solve it or if the is another function to work with projected data?

Here the script I was using and the error:

```
head(grid) # example of my data points

        Lon     Lat
1 -124195.7 4986652
2 -120195.7 4986652
3 -116195.7 4986652
4 -112195.7 4986652
5 -108195.7 4986652
6 -104195.7 4986652

summary(etopo1) # ETOPO1 already reprojected and converte to class "bathy" object

# Bathymetric data of class 'bathy', with 1329 rows and 709 columns
# Latitudinal range: 4306614.28 to 5618264.28 (4306614.28 N to 5618264.28 N)
# Longitudinal range: -550748.25 to 1203531.75 (550748.25 W to 1203171.75 E)
# Cell size: 79258.1 minute(s)

# Depth statistics:
#     Min.  1st Qu.   Median     Mean  3rd Qu.     Max.     NA's
# -5586.23 -4004.18   -99.56 -1392.81   244.61  2928.77   141413 

# First 3 columns and rows of the bathymetric matrix:

#                   4306614.27700283 4308466.88999718 4310319.50299153 
# -550748.253167697               NA               NA               NA               
# -549427.259191793               NA               NA               NA               
# -548106.265215889               NA               NA               NA          

##  Try to obtain the closest distance to the coast 

DistCoast <- dist2isobath(etopo1, grid[,1:2], isobath=0)

Error in .pointsToMatrix(p) : longitude < -360
```

Answer (score 0):

Under the hood, `dist2isobath()` uses the `dist2Line()` function from the `geosphere` package, which relies on the `pointsToMatrix()` function from the same package ([see code here](https://github.com/cran/geosphere/blob/master/R/pointsToMatrix.R)). `pointsToMatrix()` expects the points to be unprojected.

So I think all you have to do is remove the projection of your points instead of projecting the batymetry you acquired from etopo1. etopo1's datum is already WGS84, and `dist2isobath()` is designed to work with it: you'll only get accurate distances computations with unprojected data.

Comment: Thank you Benoit, the thing is that I already have all these distances calculated with unprojected data (i.e. I'm working with habitat models and I had predicted all my models with unprojected data). However, what I need for the next step is create a projected grid with the same data, i.e. extract again the distances but with projection. I know that the distances are more accurate with unprojected data, but I need to looking for a way to solve it with a projection...Thank you!

Comment: I'm afraid I don't get it then. If you already computed "unprojected distances", that's it. Projecting shouldn't affect geographic distances, it only affects the visual display of geographic information (e.g. how the paths are represented on a 2D map). Another way of saying it is that no matter what projection you chose to visualise your data or shortest paths, the geographic distances are always the same (i.e. a number of meters/kilometers). Am I missing something obvious? Best.